# Redirect process standard input in Task

Tags: c#, process, task, stdin, streamwriter

I'm trying to start a process In C# (Java.exe running a jar file) in a seperate thread, and redirect it's StandardInput, StandardError and StandardOutput.

I've successfully redirect StandardError and StandardOutput, but I am having problems with StandardInput.
I'm starting the process this way:

```
Action<object> MyAction = (object obj) =>
{
    MyProcess.Start();
    MyProcess.WaitForExit();
};
Task MyTask = new Task(MyAction);
MyTask.Start();
```

What I need then is to be able to, in my windows forms application, to have a textbox and a button, where I can input commands that will be sent to the process StandardInput but I cannot find a way to redirect it "outside the task", from what i'm aware it requires a streamWriter, but I cannot find a way to write to it when it is running in a seperate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `StandardInput` and `StandardOutput` before passing them in to the `Task`:

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private StreamWriter _streamWriter;
    private StreamReader _streamReader;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InitializeProcess(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
           UseShellExecute = false,
           ErrorDialog = false, 
           RedirectStandardError = true,
           RedirectStandardInput = true, 
           RedirectStandardOutput = true                 
        }

        var myProcess = new Process(processStartInfo);

        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            MyProcess.Start();
            MyProcess.WaitForExit();
        });

        _streamWriter = MyProcess.StandardInput;
        _streamReader = MyProcess.StandardOutput;
    }

    public void ButtonEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _streamWriter.Writer( /* write stuff here */ )  
    }
}
```

That way, as long as the process lives, you can access its streams. Note you will have to add a check to make sure the process is still alive, and eventually dispose your `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader`

**Edit**

Instead of using a threadpool thread just to block waiting for `WaitForExit`, we can register to the asynchronous `Process.Exited` event:

```
    public void InitializeProcess(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
           UseShellExecute = false,
           ErrorDialog = false, 
           RedirectStandardError = true,
           RedirectStandardInput = true, 
           RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        }

        var myProcess = new Process(processStartInfo);
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        myProcess.Exited += (s, e) => 
        { 
            // Do whatever you want when process ends, like 
            // Disposing of the streams.
        }

        myProcess.Start();

        _streamWriter = MyProcess.StandardInput;
        _streamReader = MyProcess.StandardOutput;
        myProcess.Start();
    }
```

Comment: All I get is an exception telling me the standardin hasn't been redirected (despite adding MinecraftProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;)

Comment: Did you set `ShellExecute` to false?

Comment: Yes, also won't work with output/error

I had to use this to read the standardOutput:
    public void AppendTextBox(string value)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
                return;
            }
            myConsole.AppendText(value);
        }

Comment: What you're doing is invoking the action of the UI thread. How does that have anything to do with stdout?

Comment: I edited my answer. Trying setting the redirect after executing `Task.Run`

Comment: The redirect still fails after Task.run

Comment: No Unfortunately not, The application still "freezes" up while the process is running, making it impossible for me to interact with it (such as pressing the "stop" button to stop the gameserver process, or typing in the command textbox/pressing the "send" button to write to the standardInput)

Comment: Really? The second piece of code should definitely not freeze you UI. There is no call to `WaitForExit` which should hang while your process start. Are you sure you got it right?

Comment: No luck, I have the following code in my StartServer() method:
http://pastebin.com/tXCQJpXu  It still hangs when the process is running. (I am completely unable to interact with the application, can't even press the red X to close it.)

Comment: You have a `while` loop here: `WriteFromGameToConsole(MinecraftProcess.StandardOutput);`. Debug it and see if it exits

Comment: That's the thing, it's not supposed to untill the process ends.. I need to continously read the standardout and standarderror WHILE the process lives to "live" update the "console" (textbox) with the gameservers log (like player chat and the like). and it's the only way I can find to do so.

Comment: Try reading it in a background thread using `Task.Run`. Or, you can also use the asynchronous read events of the `Process` class

Comment: I don't see how that would work, to let me continously get the output (in the form of lines of text continously from the minecraft server, like a chat output), while still letting the program do other things?

Comment: I have managed to get it working by using Task.Run (and working with the output/error streams within that) while using the standardinput stream outside.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect is would be easy to have StandardInput to be accessible across (parallel) tasks.
Which of two parallel tasks with both access to StandardInput should get its input?

I would indeed think that you'd need some programming of buffers and/or streams.

Also, are you sure that you want to sent to StandardInput process? It typically is read only. (Though it can be the StandardOutput of some other task/process)

Comment: It's a game server process, that i'd like to send commands to (Minecraft), the application is meant to manage several of then running at once and not lock up the application itself as they run, thus I felt running them in a seperate thread was needed, as not doing so seemed to lock up the application untill the game process ended (which it shouldn't)